Altium Designer: How can I add an alternative schematic symbol to a component imported from Manufacturer Part Search?
My experience with Altium Designer is still limited. (I have 15+ years experience with Orcad). One thing I struggle with are the libraries.
Many times the Manufacturer Part Search works great. But sometimes I want to do modifications to the components in my schematic. For example the resistors. I have a preference for the European symbols. Now many resistors from the MPS have this as an 'alternate' symbol, but some have not. I would like to add the European symbol to the latter because a schematic with mixed kinds of symbols looks very unprofessional. But what's the preferred way to accomplish this? I have tried copying components to local libraries and editing the components there, but somehow the link between the schematic symbol and footprint (and 3D model) always gets broken.
Also, does Altium have libraries with standard footprints like for example a 0805 resistor?
This could be a good alternative way instead of extracting the footprint from an imported component. But I havent's been able to find those yet.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

That link leads me to the Altium frontpage, not to a forum

ok.  How about https://resources.altium.com/p/getting-connected-altiums-user-community-forums

...or on the original link (forum.live.altium.com), click on "Register an account" near the bottom right, under "Sign In".
